# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in PopupWindow?

Tags: android

I can see a very strange cash in my Android app reported by Firebase Crashlytics:

```
android.util.ArrayMap.valueAt (ArrayMap.java:439)
android.transition.Transition.forceToEnd (Transition.java:1956)
android.transition.TransitionManager.endTransitions (TransitionManager.java:452)
android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView$4.onViewDetachedFromWindow (PopupWindow.java:2567)
android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow (View.java:18421)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow (ViewGroup.java:3777)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow (ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie (ViewRootImpl.java:6778)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.die (ViewRootImpl.java:6755)
android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked (WindowManagerGlobal.java:458)
android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView (WindowManagerGlobal.java:396)
android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate (WindowManagerImpl.java:126)
android.widget.PopupWindow.dismissImmediate (PopupWindow.java:1987)
android.widget.PopupWindow.access$200 (PopupWindow.java:106)
android.widget.PopupWindow$3.onTransitionEnd (PopupWindow.java:1926)
android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView.lambda$startExitTransition$0 (PopupWindow.java:2500)
android.widget.-$$Lambda$PopupWindow$PopupDecorView$T99WKEnQefOCXbbKvW95WY38p_I.run (-.java:8)
android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView$2.onTransitionEnd (PopupWindow.java:2519)
android.transition.Transition.end (Transition.java:1926)
android.transition.Transition$3.onAnimationEnd (Transition.java:1877)
android.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd (Animator.java:552)
android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation (ValueAnimator.java:1232)
android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame (ValueAnimator.java:1474)
android.animation.AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame (AnimationHandler.java:146)
android.animation.AnimationHandler.access$100 (AnimationHandler.java:37)
android.animation.AnimationHandler$1.doFrame (AnimationHandler.java:54)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1010)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:823)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:755)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:998)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6859)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

It happens on different [mostly on Lenovo and unknown] devices on Android 9 (`PopupWindow.java line 2567`) and does not include app code in the stacktrace. Similar error happens on Android 8 but the line is different (`PopupWindow.java:2565`).

What can be done to have more details on it or how can it be fixed? The app does not use `PopupWindow` directly.

Comment: You should provide more information, but the documentation says "For indices outside of the range 0...size()-1, the behavior is undefined for apps targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.P and earlier" for android.util.ArrayMap.valueAt(), and this refers to version 9 and earlier.

Comment: The problem is that there is no app code involved here (at least nothing in the call stack)

Comment: Probably raised by an API if your app uses one

Comment: @Zain can you explain what you mean?

Comment: If you used an API and drag it in gradle dependency in your app... if it has an internal popup window that is used behind the scenes for some functionality this may be the reason

Comment: What do you mean by " The app does not use PopupWindow directly" ??

Comment: Please be a bit clear. post your code for creation and usage of Popup here. it'll make people inspect /understand about the root cause for your crash @4ntoine

Comment: @pramod_m no PopupWindow is used in the app source code